# Why is my plot3d white in SciLab?

Tags: scilab

```
t = 0:%pi/50:10*%pi;
plot3d(sin(t),cos(t),t)
```

When I execute this code the plot is done but the line is not visible, only the box. Any ideas which property I have to change?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The third argument should, in this case, be a matrix of the size (length arg1) x (length arg2).

You'd expect `plot3d` to behave like an extension of `plot` and `plot2d` but it isn't quite the case.

The 2d plot takes a vector of x and a vector of y and plots points at (x1,y1), (x2,y2) etc., joined with lines or not as per style settings. That fits the conceptual model we usually use for 2d plots - charting the relationship of one thing as a function of another, in most cases (y = f(x)). THere are other ways to use a 2d plot: scatter graphs are common but it's easy enough to produce one using the two-rows-of-data concept.

This doesn't extend smoothly to 3d though as there are many other ways you could use a 3d plot to represent data. If you gave it three vectors of coordinates and asked it to draw a line between them all what might we want to use that for? Is that the most useful way of using a 3d plot?

Most packages give you different visualisation types for the different kinds of data. Mathematica has a lot of 3d visualisation types and Python/Scipy/Mayavi2 has even more. Matlab has a number too but Scilab, while normally mirroring Matlab, in this case prefers to handle it all with the `plot3d` function.

I think of it like a contour plot: you give it a vector of x and a vector of y and it uses those to create a grid of (x,y) points. The third argument is then a matrix whose dimensions match those of the (x,y) grid holding the z-coordinates of each point. The first example in the [docs](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.3/en_US/plot3d.html) does what I think you're after:

```
t=[0:0.3:2*%pi]';
z=sin(t)*cos(t');
plot3d(t,t,z);
```

The first line creates a column vector of length 21

```
-->size(t)
 ans  =

    21.    1.
```

The second line computes a 21 x 21 matrix of products of the permutations of sin(t) with cos(t) - note the transpose in the `cos(t')` element.

```
-->size(z)
 ans  =

    21.    21.
```

Then when it plots them it draws (x1,y1,z11), (x1,y2,x12), (x2,y2,z22) and so on. It draws lines between adjacent points in a mesh, or no lines, or just the surface.